# How to password protect a ZIP file in Win 10 without using external program?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, zip

How can I password protect a zip file in Win 10, without using an external program such as 7-zip etc.?

Comment: What about `cipher /e “here input the full path of the file you want to encrypt”`?

Comment: you can't. Neither the built in .NET `IO.Compression.ZipFile` nor the PowerShell `Compress-Archive` command has an option for adding a password. [How can you zip or unzip from the script using ONLY Windows' built-in capabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546016/995714)

Answer (score 2):

You cant natively  password protect a zip file (yet) in Win10.

But you can install a portable version (like [7-Zip portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable)) on a removable drive.
This way you don't have to install anything on the OS.

Answer (score -4):

Step 1: Using the right mouse button, click on the ZIP file that you would like to password protect.

Step 2: In the shortcut menu, select the “Properties” option to open the file properties.

Step 3: In the “General” tab, click on “Advanced” in order to open the “Advanced Attribute” dialog window.

Step 4: In the “Advanced Attributes” dialog window, select the check box next to “Encrypt contents to secure data”.

Step 5: Close the “Advanced Attributes” dialog window by clicking on “OK” and save the change in file properties by clicking on “OK” or “Apply”.

And then the file icon is display in padlock.This indicates that the corresponding file is password protected.

Comment: that's [NTFS encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Encryption) and not related to zip in anyway. It just encrypts files for one user so that other users can't open it

Comment: Additionally, this isn't password protected encryption. It's tied to the Windows user account that encrypted it, and can only be decrypted by that user or an administrator with a recovery certificate.